# Proving that either of the two numbers are greater or equal to their arithmetic mean.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

The arithmetic mean of two numbers $x$ and $y$ is $k$. Show that either $x \ge k$
or $y \ge k$.
Can anyone explain what approach should I use?

Answer (score 2):

This can be proved using the contrapositive of the given implication.

Suppose $x<k$ and $y<k$.

Then, the arithmetic mean, $a = \frac{x+y}{2}<\frac{2k}{2}=k$

That is, $a< k$.

Thus, if the arithmetic mean is $k$, then either $x\ge k$ or $y\ge k$.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$k = (x+y)/2$,

$\begin{array}\\
(x-k)(y-k)
&=(x-(x+y)/2)(y-(x+y)/2)\\
&=\frac{x-y}{2}\frac{y-x}{2}\\
&=-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4}\\
&\le 0
\qquad\text{with equality only if }x=y\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $x \ne y$,
$x-k$ and $y-k$ have
different signs,
so that either
$x-k < 0$ and $y-k > 0$
or
$x-k > 0$ and $y-k < 0$.

If $x=y$,
then
$0
= (x-k)(y-k)
= (x-k)^2
$
so
$x = y = k$.